# Can I have sifrei kodesh in my bedroom?

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, rambam

Since I may be naked in my bedroom, is it possible to have sifrei kodesh in it (according to the Talmud or the Rambam)?

Comment: "according to the Talmud or the Rambam" Why such a limited range of sources?

Comment: "I may be naked in my bedroom": do you mean that it's possible for you to be naked or that it's permissible? If the latter, can you provide evidence of this claim?

Answer (score 1):

Rav D Neustadt has a [review](http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5770/shlach.html) of the respect to be paid to Sefarim.

Relevant to your question is the statement (with my translation in the reference):

Sefarim are treated with kedushah. Thus:
It is prohibited for males (over the age of nine) or females (over the age of three) to be completely unclothed in the presence of a sefer.[ref. 24]

ref. 24: Mishnah Berurah 45:5, 75:23. But this prohibition applies only to ervah mamash (*real nakedness*); we do not invoke tefach b'ishah ervah  (*a hands-breadth of a female uncovered is prohibited*)  concerning this issue; Rabbi P.E. Falk (Kol ha-Torah, vol. 46, pgs. 187-194).

45:5 references Gem Berochos 60.

Comment: Can you summarize what the referenced Gemara says in this regard?